# Cannot build lynx on windows with cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, compile, make, openssl

There are many Windows builds of Lynx available over the 'net, but none of them support HTTPS, so I was trying to build with SSL enabled, among other things.

The `./configure` part is successful, but the building runs into errors while trying to `make`. GCC complains of various errors with the OpenSSL header files itself.

`./configure` was run with the following options:

```
$ ./configure --enable-nls --with-ssl --with-gnutls --enable-gnutls-compat --enable-ipv6 --enable-ascii-ctypes --enable-japanese-utf8 --enable-charset-choice --enable-kbd-layout --enable-nested-tables --enable-progressbar --enable-scrollbar --enable-sessions --enable-sessions-cache --with-zlib
```

(I'll post the output of the above if anyone requires it)

Output of `make`:

```
$ make
/bin/sh -c 'SHELL=/bin/sh /bin/sh ./scripts/cfg_defs.sh .'
Constructing sed-script help_files.sed
sed     -e '/^#/d' -e '/^$/d' \
        -e 's%\(.*\)=\(.*\@.*\)$%s=@\1@=\2=g%' \
        -e 's%\(.*\)=\(http:.*\)$%s=@\1@=\2=g%' \
        -e 's%\(.*\)=\(ftp:.*\)$%s=@\1@=\2=g%' \
        -e 's%\(.*\)=\(.*\.html\)$%s=@\1@=\2=g%' \
        help_files.tmp | tr '=' '"' > help_files.sed
Appending interim-fix for existing html files to help_files.sed
sed     -e '/^#/d' -e '/[:@]/d' -e '/^$/d' \
        -e 's%\(.*\)=\(.*\.html\)$%s=\2=\2=g%' \
        -e 's%\.html=%\\.html=%' \
        help_files.tmp | tr '=' '"' >> help_files.sed
if test -n ""; then echo 's%\\%%g' >> help_files.sed; fi
Creating LYHelp.h
**********************************************

       Help files will NOT be gzipped.

**********************************************
/bin/sh ./scripts/fixtext.sh ./LYMessages_en.h >LYMessages.c
cd ./po && make DESTDIR="" CC="gcc"
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/lynx/po'
msginit --no-translator -l en -i lynx.pot
Created en.po.
file=./`echo en | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && PATH=../src:$PATH /usr/bin/msgfmt.exe -o $file en.po
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/lynx/po'
cd ./WWW/Library/Implementation && make DESTDIR="" CC="gcc" LY_CFLAGS="-O2 "  CPPFLAGS="-U_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600  -DWIN_EX -D_WINDOWS_NSL"  LYFLAGS=""
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/lynx/WWW/Library/Implementation'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I../../..  -I../../../src  -I../../..  -I../../../src   -I../../../WWW/Library/Implementation  -U_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600  -DWIN_EX -D_WINDOWS_NSL -O2    -I../../../WWW/Library/Implementation/ -DACCESS_AUTH -c ../../../WWW/Library/Implementation/HTParse.c
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/crypto.h:131:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/comp.h:5,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:149,
                 from ../../../WWW/Library/Implementation/HTUtils.h:685,
                 from ../../../WWW/Library/Implementation/HTParse.c:8:
/usr/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:153:29: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:199:33: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:156:0,
                 from ../../../WWW/Library/Implementation/HTUtils.h:685,
                 from ../../../WWW/Library/Implementation/HTParse.c:8:
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:199:1: error: pasting "stack_st_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:199:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:210:34: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:235:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:254:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:330:3: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:453:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘(’ token
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:600:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:156,
                 from ../../../WWW/Library/Implementation/HTUtils.h:685,
                 from ../../../WWW/Library/Implementation/HTParse.c:8:
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:150:50: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:152:56: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:203:56: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:204:59: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:253:56: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:254:59: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:407:7: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:408:80: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:415:59: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:416:62: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:443:59: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:459:56: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:461:62: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:601:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:156,
                 from ../../../WWW/Library/Implementation/HTUtils.h:685,
                 from ../../../WWW/Library/Implementation/HTParse.c:8:
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:88:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:104:4: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:106:1: error: pasting "stack_st_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:106:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘LPCSTR’
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: error: pasting ")" and "_new" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: error: pasting ")" and "_free" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘LPCSTR’
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: error: pasting "d2i_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: error: pasting "i2d_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: error: ‘i2d_’ declared as function returning a function
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: error: pasting ")" and "_it" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:314:27: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:316:28: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:317:33: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:322:23: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:323:48: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:331:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘LPCSTR’
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:331:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:333:46: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:338:34: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:348:32: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:350:26: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:352:32: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:353:39: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:354:33: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:356:26: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:362:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘LPCSTR’
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:362:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:374:31: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:376:42: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:379:35: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:380:36: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:381:30: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:156:0,
                 from ../../../WWW/Library/Implementation/HTUtils.h:685,
                 from ../../../WWW/Library/Implementation/HTParse.c:8:
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:632:24: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:679:28: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:679:44: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:772:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘LPCSTR’
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:772:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:829:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘LPCSTR’
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:829:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:829:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:829:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:829:1: error: pasting ")" and "_it" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:833:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘LPCSTR’
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:833:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:833:1: error: pasting ")" and "_new" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:833:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:833:1: error: pasting ")" and "_free" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:833:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘LPCSTR’
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:833:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:833:1: error: pasting "d2i_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:833:1: error: pasting "i2d_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:833:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:833:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:833:1: error: ‘i2d_’ declared as function returning a function
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:833:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:833:1: error: pasting ")" and "_it" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:835:20: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:835:36: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:842:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘LPCSTR’
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:842:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:842:1: error: pasting ")" and "_new" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:842:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:842:1: error: pasting ")" and "_free" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:842:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘LPCSTR’
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:842:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:842:1: error: pasting "d2i_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:842:1: error: pasting "i2d_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:842:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:842:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:842:1: error: ‘i2d_’ declared as function returning a function
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:842:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:842:1: error: pasting ")" and "_it" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:883:27: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:912:37: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:913:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘LPCSTR’
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:913:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:914:38: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:915:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘LPCSTR’
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:915:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:924:46: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:953:43: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:980:26: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:980:40: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:981:30: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:982:34: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:991:37: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:995:31: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:996:34: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:1006:29: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:1007:33: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:1009:32: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:1014:34: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:1015:34: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:1017:38: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:1018:41: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:1019:27: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:1021:32: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:1023:32: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:1029:32: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:1153:57: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:1155:47: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:162:0,
                 from ../../../WWW/Library/Implementation/HTUtils.h:685,
                 from ../../../WWW/Library/Implementation/HTParse.c:8:
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:158:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:463:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘LPCSTR’
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:463:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:463:1: error: pasting "PEM_read_bio_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:463:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘LPCSTR’
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:463:1: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:463:1: error: pasting "PEM_read_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:463:1: error: pasting "PEM_write_bio_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:463:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:463:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:463:1: error: ‘PEM_write_bio_’ declared as function returning a function
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:463:1: error: pasting "PEM_write_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:463:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:463:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/openssl/pem.h:463:1: error: ‘PEM_write_’ declared as function returning a function
In file included from ../../../WWW/Library/Implementation/HTUtils.h:685:0,
                 from ../../../WWW/Library/Implementation/HTParse.c:8:
/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1289:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘(’ token
makefile:312: recipe for target `HTParse.o' failed
make[1]: *** [HTParse.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/lynx/WWW/Library/Implementation'
makefile:191: recipe for target `all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone have ideas about how to work around this issue (other than disabling SSL, which I require)?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit WWW/Library/Implementation/HTUtils.h like so. Change:

```
#if defined(__CYGWIN__)         /* 1998/12/31 (Thu) 16:13:46 */
#include <windows.h>            /* #include "windef.h" */
```

To:

```
#if defined(__CYGWIN__)         /* 1998/12/31 (Thu) 16:13:46 */
#define NOCRYPT
#include <windows.h>            /* #include "windef.h" */
#include <openssl/bio.h>
```